# "On the parking lot" - Is it correct?

Tags: prepositions

Can you say "I left my car back on the parking lot"?

I know that people usually use *in*. Is it absolutely incorrect to use *on*?
Because I saw they use *on* in this bilingual magazine [Báo Song Ngữ](http://docbaotienganh.com/)

Comment: Please stop using "true" incorrectly. *True* does not mean *grammatical*.

Comment: @tchrist *Stop*? Have you known the OP for long?

Comment: "Is it absolutely incorrect to use *on* ?" No, it is not incorrect. It depends on the sentence. Can you show the complete sentence where it was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we mean 'the surface' the preposition 'on' is used.
If we mean 'the space, like underground parking'   I would use 'in'.

Answer (score 1):

I walk *in* a park but I walk *on* a pavement (or sidewalk if you're American)

Why is this relevant? Because a park is a deliniated space which could be enclosed with walls or fences whilst a thoroughfare is not: by definition a thoroughfare passes between places, it's not a place in its own right.

Similarly I can leave my car *on* a street but *in* a car park (or parking lot if you're American) because the street is a thoroughfare and the car park is a deliniated space which could be enclosed (many are).

The same applies to fields, there is an old joke that an academic is a man outstanding in his field but a farmer is a man, out, standing in his field. This wouldn't work if we didn't habitually speak of being *in* rather than *on* a field.

I can, however, leave my car *on* a garage forecourt. This is because, although the forecourt is defined in law it is not, usually, deliniated physically so is considered in some sense to be part of the thoroughfare onto which it faces.

The only other space I can think of which I would refer to being *on* rather than *in* would be a *building plot* or a *vacant lot*. Since Americans refer to open car parks as *parking lots* I can understand why there is some flexibility in the use of *in* and *on* but a *parking lot* is a space set aside for parking cars so it becomes a deliniated space and therefore *in* is more appropriate. I would only speak about leaving my car *on* a *vacant* lot.

**Update** 
I've just thought of another space which I would speak of as being *on*, that is a sports field or pitch. However sports fields are usually part of another area like a stadium or recreational park and are, therefore, more like the stage of a theatre, One is *in* the stadium or park even if one is *on* the field of play. Also we don't often get to park cars *on* the field of play:-)